# Mobile network: browser is OK, apps doesn't connect internet

Tags: applications, wi-fi

When phone use WiFi connection, all apps can connect to internet. When it use mobile network connection, browser can connect, but apps cann't connect. Is there any settings? How can I diagnose? Phone is Sony Ericsson Xperia X8 with Android 2.1.

Comment: What's your carrier?

Comment: Orange Slovakia

Answer (score 1):

I think the most interesting is you **APN** and **Operator**. It could be that only **http** traffic is allowed (port 80 and 443 for https) or some similar limitation. Check you operators support page for details.

Comment: Opera Mini also cann't connect, but browser can.

Answer (score 0):

In my country there is one operator with whom we've same behavior. They have given us two different **apn**. With first only the browser works, exactly like you have said. With second everything works.

If your operator has different **apn** for using Mobile internet in Computer, try that **apn**. This works with one of the operator in my country but not sure if this will help you.