# Wifi issue on my Nexus 4

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-4

I recently updated android version to 4.4.2 on my Nexus 4. After this update my apps like "watsapp", "LINE", "VIBER" are having connectivity issue when connecting through WiFi, But I could open the browser and could access the web pages. I didn't have this issue with the previous android version.
Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Sanzee! That's a question we've got multiple times already. Please check: [Mobile network: browser is OK, apps doesn't connect internet](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11963/16575) / [Unable to use apps that access the Internet on wifi](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13421/16575) / [Only whatsapp working on Wi-Fi and no other apps connecting(Android)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55660/16575). Does any of those help you?

Comment: The mentioned links are not appropriate for me.

Comment: Mind to explain why? We could help you better with some more background. Please [edit] your question and add why those questions (or rather their answers) don't match your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned problem seems to be coming after updation to android version to 4.4.2 you may want to refer to [android-4-3-no-internet-access-unable-to-connect-to-the-proxy-server-error](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50273/android-4-3-no-internet-access-unable-to-connect-to-the-proxy-server-error).

The reason seems to be If you have cleared your Google Service Framework data to recieve the update, it will change your device ID that google uses to recognise your device.